# Google Storageclient.ListObjects causes thread cancel when deployed to server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-storage

I have some code that fetches files from Google Cloud Storage. The code works fine when run on my local development machine but when deployed to our production server it always "stops" whenever the parameter "objectsInBucket" (in the code below) is used.

In the example below the last code that actually executes correctly when deployed to the server is the line "LogHelper.LogToConsole("-6").

If I "uncomment" the foreach loop the last output to console is "- 4". Also, if I for example make a variable like "var count = objectsInBucket.Count();" and put it immediately after "objectsInBucket = storageClient.Listobjects(_gcsBucketName);" then the last output will be "- 1".

But like I said, this problem only occurs when deployed to the server. So what can the cause of this be?

```
 Google.Api.Gax.PagedEnumerable<Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Objects, Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object> objectsInBucket = null;
                
 LogHelper.LogToConsole($" - 1");
 objectsInBucket = storageClient.ListObjects(_gcsBucketName);
 LogHelper.LogToConsole($" - 2");
 //var count = objectsInBucket.Count(); // this causes last output to be "- 2"
 var dirPath = Path.Combine(_gcsAttachemntPath, attachmentId);
 LogHelper.LogToConsole($" - 3");

 if (objectsInBucket != null)
 {
    LogHelper.LogToConsole($" - 4");
    //LogHelper.LogToConsole($" - {objectsInBucket.Count()} attachments exists on bucket:");
    //foreach (var obj in objectsInBucket)
    //{
    //    LogHelper.LogToConsole($" - - {obj.Name}");
    //}
     LogHelper.LogToConsole($" - 5");
     var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
     if (directoryInfo.Exists)
     {
       LogHelper.LogToConsole($" - Deleting directory: {dirPath}");
       directoryInfo.Delete(true);
     }
    
    directoryInfo.Create();
    LogHelper.LogToConsole($" - Directory created: {dirPath}");
 }
 
 LogHelper.LogToConsole($" - 6");
 var attachmentFiles = objectsInBucket.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(attachmentId));
```

Comment: Permissions? You don't include sufficient code to repro your experience (making it harder to help) but hopefully you're using Application Default Credentials. When you run the code locally, you're probably using `gcloud auth application-default` credentials that leverage your User account (and its permissions). When you run on a compute service, you're using the instance's identity and it has different permissions.

Comment: We connect to a project/bucket using credentials from a json-file containing project_id, Private_key_id, private_key etc, We use same credentials on dev machine as on the server. To maybe give some more info I can add that the code is reading messages from a message queue and if a message has an attachment Iread that attachment and that's when I user the "StorageClient.ListObjects" which gives a "A task was canceled"-error when deployed to server. So, reading messages works fine but reading the attachments does not..(on the server)

Comment: It's very difficult to solve issues by an extended series of comments and it doesn't provide reusable content for others. You should **not** use a Service Account key (JSON file) directly when deployed to a compute service. You should (and may be) use the compute service's instance's credentials. I suspect (!) that you **are** in fact using the instance's credentails and not the JSON file when deployed to Google Cloud and this identity doesn't have the correct Cloud Storage permissions. Good luck!

Comment: can you have a look at my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answers were much appreciated.

It turns out that for some reason this call was blocked in the firewall on the server.
We were made available a proxy to use when doing these calls.
Then, when using the proxy, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you shared It seems you want to achieve this:  If an object exists in the  folder you want to delete the object and create a subfolder in the same folder.If it does not exist create a subfolder directly in the folder..I am not much experienced in C# the below code may help you i think.

```
StorageClient storageClient = StorageClient.Create(projectId);
string bucketName = "bucketName";
string folderName = "folderToCreate";
string objectName = "ObjectToCheckToExist";
bool objectExists = storageClient.GetObject(bucketName, $"{folderName}/{objectName}") != null;
if (objectExists){   
 storageClient.DeleteObject(bucketName, $"{folderName}/{objectName}");
 storageClient.DeleteFolder(bucketName, folderName);
}
else {
    storageClient.CreateFolder(bucketName, folderName);
}
```

Also have a look at [official document](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClient) as well.